# android app: missing menu items on api level 15

Tags: android, menu, android-emulator, android-actionbar, menuitem

On my activity, I add 5 items in the menu.xml file, all of which have the attribute `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`. My target sdk level is 19, and minimum sdk level is 11.

When running on an emulator with resolution **480 x 800** and target api level 19, it shows 3 items directly on the Action Bar, and the last two items are tucked in the menu which can be accessed via the ellipsis button. All is fine.

Now when I try to test on an emulator with api level 15, it still shows 3 items on the Action Bar, but I don't see the ellipsis (3-dot) button to open the menu drop down. In other words, there's no way to access the last two menu items.

Any thought on how I can bring back the menu on api level 15?

Thanks

Comment: Does that emulator also perchance have a menu button? If so, there will never be an overflow button in the action bar. I'm pretty sure the overflow icon will always be present in the action bar otherwise (though I think this behavior has changed with KitKat).

Comment: Sorry, I've just changed my question. I discovered that the behavior is different when I target different api level. My emulator doesn't have any menu button. I chose No Skin option.